# display current time in different textfield JAVA

Tags: java

I'm trying to display current time in different textfields Java. For example for seconds (ss) I have to split two integers (ss) in two separate text fields(so for example 58' will be 5 in one textfield and 8 in another textfield). Is there any method to use in order to split current time seconds in two different text fields?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you just split a String (consists of two characters) into two Strings (consists of a character)?

Comment: "For example" leads me to think there's more going on here than just splitting a two digit number into its digits... What are you *really* looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If time is a string you can do:

```
String time = "60"; // get time from your function in some string
String textField1 = time.substring(0,0); // gets "6"
String textField2 = time.substring(1); // gets "0"
```

If time is an integer you can do (when time is less than 100):

```
int time = 60; // get time from your function 0-99
int textField1 = (int) time/10; // takes a number, forces it to be int after
                                // dividing by ten (ex: 65/10 = 6.5 -> 6)
int textField2 = (int) time - (textField1 * 10); // finds the first place digit
                                                 // by making it subtract the second place
                                                 // (ex: 65 - (6*10) = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks , that seem to be working for me . :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help